# How to have valid references to objects owned by containers that dynamically move their objects?

Tags: pointers, reference, dangling-pointer

If you have a pointer or reference to an object contained in a container, say a dynamic array or a hash table/map, there's the problem that the objects don't permanently stay there, and so it seems any references to these objects become invalid before too long. For example a dynamic array might need to reallocate, and a hash table might have to rehash, changing the positions of the buckets in the array.

In languages like Java (and I think C#), and probably most languages this may not be a problem. In these languages many things are references instead of the object itself. You can create a reference to the 3rd element of a dynamic array, you basically create a new reference by copying the reference to the object which lives somewhere else.

But in say C++ where a dynamic array or hash table will actually store the objects directly in its memory owned by the container what are you supposed to do? There's only one place where the object I create can live. I can create the object by allocating it somewhere, and then store pointers to that object in a dynamic array or a hash table, or any other container. However if I decide to have the container be the owner of those objects I run into problems with having a pointer or reference to those objects.

In the case of a dynamic array like an std::vector you can reference an object in the array with a index instead of a memory address. If the array is reallocated the index is still valid. However I run into the same problem if I remove an element in the array, then the index is potentially no longer valid.

In the case of something like a hash table, the table might dynamically rehash, changing the position of all the values in the buckets. Is the only way of having references to hash table values to just search for or hash the key every time you want to access it?

What are the ways of having references to objects that live in containers like these, or any others?

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any magic or generally used solutions to this. You have to make tradeoffs. If you are optimizing things at this low level, one good approach might be to use a container class that informs you when it does a reallocation. It'd be interesting to find out if there is any container library with this property

Comment: It seems to be a hard problem. It would also have to inform me when do a remove or insert. And then I would need to hunt down all the references to those elements, which means I would have to record them all? Hmm, I wonder how this is handled.

Comment: Record, or possibly your code would know your data structures and what needs updating. Now sure what you mean about removes and inserts, you already know when you're removing an element. And when inserting, you just need to get the address of the added element.